# Resetting TCP connection programmingly in Scrapy

Tags: python, http, https, tcp, scrapy

I'm currently crawling a website that bans IP if it requested too many pages in a short period of time. When that happens, it gives a `403 status code` in the response. If the IP address doesn't renew, the crawler will fail all the following requests.

So I added an HTTP proxy, it is a hub hosting hundreds of IPs and assigns a random one per TCP connection.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> proxies = {"https": "https://user:pass@proxyservice.com"}
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> 
>>> print("\n persisted connection:")
>>> for i in range(3):
>>>     print(s.get("https://ifconfig.co", proxies=proxies).text)
>>>
>>> print("\n new connection every request:")
>>> for i in range(3):
>>>     print(requests.get("https://ifconfig.co", proxies=proxies).text)

persisted connection:
123.123.123.123
123.123.123.123
123.123.123.123

new connection every request:
123.111.111.111
123.222.222.222
123.110.110.110
```

I working with Scrapy in my project, it uses persisted connection by default, which means it will use the same proxy IP per connection:

```py
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['ifconfig.co']
    custom_settings = {
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 2
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://ifconfig.co"
        self.headers = {"user-agent": "curl"}
        self.proxy = "https://user:pass@proxyservice.com"

    def start_requests(self):
        # We have 2 concurrent requests (persisted connections).
        yield Request(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, meta={"proxy": self.proxy}, dont_filter=True)
        yield Request(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, meta={"proxy": self.proxy}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info(response.text)
        yield Request(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, meta={"proxy": self.proxy}, dont_filter=True)
```

Which gives us:

```
2019-06-27 12:13:21 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:21 [test] INFO: 38.xx.xx.199

2019-06-27 12:13:21 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:22 [test] INFO: 38.xx.xx.199

2019-06-27 12:13:22 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:22 [test] INFO: 38.xx.xx.199

2019-06-27 12:13:22 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:23 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:23 [test] INFO: 38.xx.xx.199

2019-06-27 12:13:23 [test] INFO: 181.xx.xx.197

2019-06-27 12:13:24 [test] INFO: 38.xx.xx.199
```

How can I reset the TCP connection with the proxy server so that I can get a new IP address when the response gives a 403?

Comment: You can try to erase response.meta["cookiejar"] for that.

Comment: Why do you want to reset it? Never a good idea, and no motivation provided here.

Comment: is this a paid proxy, does it change (automatically) at every request?

Comment: @programmerwiz32 Only if using non-persistence connection. Like the example code using ‘requests.get’. But for performance it’s better using a session.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that proxy service i'm using (https://luminati.io) supports forcing IP renewal by adding a parameter into the username field.

username-session-%rndint:pass@proxyservice.com

And changing IP region by:
username-country-us:pass@proxyservice.com